# How do I authenticate to SVN server from a shell task in Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have jenkins set up to connect to an SVN server and one of my jobs I would like to `svn update` and `svn commit`.

I do this in a shell task, but it is failing.  when I make a call to:

```
svn update
```

I get the following error:

> Authentication realm: http://svn...:80 Subversion Repository
>   Password for 'jenkins': Authentication realm: http://svn...:80
>   Subversion Repository Username: svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn...':
>   authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic
>   challenge

I have googled this and looked online, but my attempts to correct my problem have not succeeded.  I would rather NOT pass `--username` and `--password` on the command line and I think there should be at least 2 other ways to set this up:

- using the 'global' Linux/SVN Jenkins user cache or something to that effect
- by passing the credentials from Jenkins

I have failed attempting to follow instructions for both of those options.

Can someone explain in terms that even an dunce like me can understand - how to configure Jenkins and my job to be able to `svn update` or `svn commit` from a shell task within a job that is hooked up to SVN.

**EDIT**
What I was asked to achieve was to run some kind of processing on some files that are not really part of the build - but we want a controlled 'build machine' to do the processing - not just any developer to do the processing and commit.

This is a manually-triggered job that takes some input, processes, then pushes the resultant files to svn.

(I don't know why it's done this way - I was brought on late to help fix their builds, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into using ssh auth, this will allow you to avoid passing username and password - as long as the key is present.

It might be worth looking at why you want to do an svn up and svn commmit form a shell step.

I would advise using the scm plugin to get the source - as soon as you do an `svn up` jenkins can't know about the changeset.

The commit may be another smell too.  short of tagging, the build pushing to svn likely has a better path. For one - you're going to have to get fancy with the hook that fires your build or it will be a loop.

Comment: I understand about the loop - this is going to be a manual job only, not triggered by scm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same problem, to run a .sh after checkout from svn(to update database scripts), and I don't know if I have to pass the user by command line or something..

In my case, I add to the .sh call two aditional parameters containing the username and password and used them..